# xunit testing to see if a specific value is there in the list

Tags: c#, xunit

I am writing x-unit testing.

I want to check if list contains the newly added value.

I tried the below code but i am not getting the result

```
_record.Add(new PortfolioCompanyLinkModel { Id = 3, PortfolioCompanyId = 1, URL = "www.historiclreports2.com", LinkName = "Historical Reports", ToBeDeleted = false, IsExternalLink = false, LinkId = 1 });
_record.Add(new PortfolioCompanyLinkModel { Id = 4, PortfolioCompanyId = 1, URL = "www.SalesForce.com", LinkName = "SalesForce", ToBeDeleted = false, IsExternalLink = false, LinkId = 2 });
var repo = new PortfolioCompanyLinkRepository(dbContext, obj.HttpContextAccessor);
var update = await repo.GetOne(2);
_record.Add(new PortfolioCompanyLinkModel { Id = update.Id, PortfolioCompanyId = update.PortfolioCompanyId, URL = "www.historiclreportstest.com", LinkName = update.Link.Name, ToBeDeleted = false, IsExternalLink = true, LinkId = update.LinkId });
var delete = await repo.GetOne(1);
_record.Add(new PortfolioCompanyLinkModel { Id = delete.Id, PortfolioCompanyId = delete.PortfolioCompanyId, URL = delete.URL, LinkName = delete.Link.Name, ToBeDeleted = true, IsExternalLink = delete.Link.IsExternalLink, LinkId = delete.LinkId });
await repo.AddUpdateDelete(_record);
await repo.SaveAsync();

var actual = await repo.GetAll();
Assert.Collection(actual, item => Assert.Contains("www.historiclreports2.com", item.URL));
```

How do i check if actual has www.historiclreports2.com as URL ?

Comment: `Assert.True(actual.Any(x = x.Url == "www.historiclreports2.com"));`

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you want to single out the record you desire to assert on. This can be done multiple ways, but the way I have do this is always as follows:

`var recordInQuestion = actual.Where(x => x.URL
       .Equals("www.historiclreports2.com"))
       .SingleOrDefault();
Assert.NotNull(recordInQuestion);`

Other options are:

`Assert.Single(actual.Where(x => x.URL.Equals("www.historiclreports2.com")));`

`Assert.True(actual.Any(x => x.URL.Equals("www.historiclreports2.com")))`

Using the first option with the `SingleOrDefault()` in which the record is assigned to a variable allows you to easily perform multiple asserts on that object's data.